# nginx url rewrite for CMS direct to /[user]/index.php

Tags: url, url-rewriting, nginx

I am attempting to move to nginx...

I have an app running in apache using the following mod_rewrite commands:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([a-z\-0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php/$2 [E=USERKEY:$1,L]
```

The PHP backed we are using processes items in the form of:

```
/[USERKEY]/index.php/[module]/[action]/[etc...]
```

We want to pass every hit (*where there is not a static file on disk*) to the **index.php** file for processing in a format where:

```
http://www.myapp.com/bobsmith/rockstar/add?q=45678
```

would translate into:

```
/var/www/some_static_path/bobsmith/index.php/rockstar/add?q=45678
```

I know some CMS products do something similar and I located a lot of examples but we have this odd USERKEY payload (*which is part of index.php's path*) causing issues for my configuration.  Additionally, I struggled dealing with the slash (/) after the index.php.  The error logs would show:

```
"/bobmsith/index.php/login" failed (20: Not a directory)
```

When attempting to browse to: http://www.myapp.com/bobsmith/login

I have tried working with rewrite, if(s), different types of location regex, try_files, fastcgi_split_path_info... I cannot find the cocktail for success!

any/all help appreciated; thanks all!